# MongoDB: Get most recent objects from embedded arrays and append parent field

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have an array of companies where each company has an array of subscription objects. A subscription object has an array of items and a date when those items was added. I want to retrieve only the most recently added subscription object from each company. I also need to be able to identify where each subscription object came from, so I need to append the company name somehow. Sorry for the confusing semantics!

**The array of companies:**

```js
[
  {
    "_id": "company1",
    "name": "Company 1",
    "subscriptions": [
      {
        "items": [
          {
            "_id": "5e13b0207b05e37f12f05beb",
            "data": 40,
            "price": 39
          },
          {
            "_id": "5e13b0207b05e37f12f05bea",
            "data": 100,
            "price": 59
          }
        ],
        "_id": "5e13b0207b05e37f12f05be9",
        "date_added": "2019-12-24T22:09:36.442Z"
      }
    ]
  },
  { "_id": "company2", "name": "Company 2", "subscriptions": [] },
  {
    "_id": "company3",
    "name": "Company 3",
    "subscriptions": [
      {
        "items": [
          {
            "_id": "5e13a47d7c370667c7e67d7a",
            "data": 40,
            "price": 69
          },
          {
            "_id": "5e13a47d7c370667c7e67d79",
            "data": 20,
            "price": 39
          }
        ],
        "_id": "5e13a47d7c370667c7e67d78",
        "date_added": "2019-12-24T21:19:57.804Z"
      },
      {
        "items": [
          {
            "_id": "5e13a4f87c370667c7e67d7d",
            "data": 35,
            "price": 39
          },
          {
            "_id": "5e13a4f87c370667c7e67d7c",
            "data": 60,
            "price": 59
          }
        ],
        "_id": "5e13a4f87c370667c7e67d7b",
        "date_added": "2020-01-04T21:22:00.832Z"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

**Desired output:**

```js
[
  {
    "name": "Company 1",
    "items": [
      {
        "_id": "5e13b0207b05e37f12f05beb",
        "data": 40,
        "price": 39
      },
      {
        "_id": "5e13b0207b05e37f12f05bea",
        "data": 100,
        "price": 59
      }
    ],
    "_id": "5e13b0207b05e37f12f05be9",
    "date_added": "2019-12-24T22:09:36.442Z"
  },
  {
    "name": "Company 3",
    "items": [
      {
        "_id": "5e13a4f87c370667c7e67d7d",
        "data": 35,
        "price": 39
      },
      {
        "_id": "5e13a4f87c370667c7e67d7c",
        "data": 60,
        "price": 59
      }
    ],
    "_id": "5e13a4f87c370667c7e67d7b",
    "date_added": "2020-01-04T21:22:00.832Z"
  }
]
```

**What I am trying:**

```js
await Companies.aggregate([
  { $unwind: '$subscriptions' },
  { $sort: { 'subscriptions.date_added': -1 } },
  { $group: { _id: '$_id' } }
])
```

**Output:**

```js
[{"_id":"company1"},{"_id":"company3"}]
```

I think I filtered out the correct objects (the most recent ones) but I am only retrieving the _id of the root element, not the nested subscription objects. These id's might be used to identify the subscriptions, but I need also need the actual subscription items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As all you want is latest subscription object, if that means if it's the last object being pushed to `subscriptions` array then, Try this :

```
Companies.aggregate([{$match : {$and :[{subscriptions: {$exists: true}}, {subscriptions: {$ne: []}}]}},
{$addFields :{subscriptions: {$arrayElemAt : ['$subscriptions',-1]} }}, {$project :{_id:0,subscriptions:1, name:1 }}])
```

**Collection data :**

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : "company1",
    "name" : "Company 1",
    "subscriptions" : [ 
        {
            "items" : [ 
                {
                    "_id" : "5e13b0207b05e37f12f05beb",
                    "data" : 40.0,
                    "price" : 39.0
                }, 
                {
                    "_id" : "5e13b0207b05e37f12f05bea",
                    "data" : 100.0,
                    "price" : 59.0
                }
            ],
            "_id" : "5e13b0207b05e37f12f05be9",
            "date_added" : "2019-12-24T22:09:36.442Z"
        }
    ]
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : "company2",
    "name" : "Company 2",
    "subscriptions" : []
}

/* 3 */
{
    "_id" : "company3",
    "name" : "Company 3",
    "subscriptions" : [ 
        {
            "items" : [ 
                {
                    "_id" : "5e13a47d7c370667c7e67d7a",
                    "data" : 40.0,
                    "price" : 69.0
                }, 
                {
                    "_id" : "5e13a47d7c370667c7e67d79",
                    "data" : 20.0,
                    "price" : 39.0
                }
            ],
            "_id" : "5e13a47d7c370667c7e67d78",
            "date_added" : "2019-12-24T21:19:57.804Z"
        }, 
        {
            "items" : [ 
                {
                    "_id" : "5e13a4f87c370667c7e67d7d",
                    "data" : 35.0,
                    "price" : 39.0
                }, 
                {
                    "_id" : "5e13a4f87c370667c7e67d7c",
                    "data" : 60.0,
                    "price" : 59.0
                }
            ],
            "_id" : "5e13a4f87c370667c7e67d7b",
            "date_added" : "2020-01-04T21:22:00.832Z"
        }
    ]
}
```

**Result :**

```
/* 1 */
{
    "name" : "Company 1",
    "subscriptions" : {
        "items" : [ 
            {
                "_id" : "5e13b0207b05e37f12f05beb",
                "data" : 40.0,
                "price" : 39.0
            }, 
            {
                "_id" : "5e13b0207b05e37f12f05bea",
                "data" : 100.0,
                "price" : 59.0
            }
        ],
        "_id" : "5e13b0207b05e37f12f05be9",
        "date_added" : "2019-12-24T22:09:36.442Z"
    }
}

/* 2 */
{
    "name" : "Company 3",
    "subscriptions" : {
        "items" : [ 
            {
                "_id" : "5e13a4f87c370667c7e67d7d",
                "data" : 35.0,
                "price" : 39.0
            }, 
            {
                "_id" : "5e13a4f87c370667c7e67d7c",
                "data" : 60.0,
                "price" : 59.0
            }
        ],
        "_id" : "5e13a4f87c370667c7e67d7b",
        "date_added" : "2020-01-04T21:22:00.832Z"
    }
}
```

Comment: @howtopythonpls : This should be simple without bulky operations like `$unwind`, `$sort` on a entire collection, Only thing you need to check is `date_added` in the last object of `subscriptions` array should be latest, if that's the case this is simple & easy. Ex:- Your `company3` first item is on `2019-12-24T21:19:57.804Z` & second is on `2020-01-04T21:22:00.832Z` this should work for you, But this query doesn't work when first item has `date_added` as `2020-01-04T21:22:00.832Z` & second item has `date_added` as `2019-12-24T21:19:57.804Z`, ideally may not be the case but depends on your data

Comment: New subscriptions are pushed to the subscriptions array so I am guessing that the latest is indeed always in the end (if mongoDB doesn't do something I am unaware of). So you would argue to use this approach over using the "bulky operations like $unwind and $sort"? I am just know trying to get more comfortable with these operations and would love to know if there are any differences in performance

Comment: @howtopythonpls : It all depends on your dataset + indexes + your mongoDB configuration, I surely cannot say that those don't work, `$unwind` & `$sort` are commonly used but there are certain limitations, maybe just not restricted to these but most of cases in aggregation it is suggested to filter out the documents as soon as possible, the lesser the documents needed to be processed the lesser the DB process time, you can use `explain` functionality in mongoDB to check your query performance, if you've less docs to work on you can use what ever aggregation stage/operator you would like to :-)

Comment: That makes sense, and I did feel kind of frustrated with having to sort all of the nested arrays before filtering out what was needed. Just doesn't feel right! I do like the approach of utilizing the structure of the objects (with most recent one being in the end). Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In your solution, you need to accumulate subscriptions with `$first` operator and with `$project` you can get desired result.

```
db.companies.aggregate([
  {
    $unwind: "$subscriptions"
  },
  {
    $sort: {
      "subscriptions.date_added": -1
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$_id",
      name: {
        $first: "$name"
      },
      subscriptions: {
        $first: "$subscriptions"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: "$subscriptions._id",
      name: "$name",
      date_added: "$subscriptions.date_added",
      items: "$subscriptions.items"
    }
  }
])
```

[MongoPlayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/fBhGFRET4JO)

Comment: Thank you for the response! I went with the other suggestion because it gave me a chance to filter before sorting instead of the other way around. It was really helpful to have your solution to compare with!